# Como usar forEach em array associativo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estou vendo aqui que o length de um array associativo em JS fica zerado.. Como eu acesso esses valores então?

Exemplo:

```js
let myArray = [];

myArray['zero'] = 0;
myArray['um'] = 1;
myArray['dois'] = 2;

console.log(myArray.length);
```

Se eu quiser dar um forEach por exemplo, eu não consigo, porque não pega nada...
Com eu faço pra acessar?

Comment: Tente `for (var key in myArray) {
    var value = myArray[key];
    console.log(key, value);
}`

Answer (score 3):

Apenas com Objeto é possível associar.

```
let myArray  = {};

myArray.zero = 0;
myArray.um   = 1;
myArray.dois = 2;

console.log(Object.keys(myArray ).length);
```

Ou

```
let myArray  = {};
let myArray  = {
   um: 1,
   dois: 2,
   tres: 3
};

console.log(Object.keys(myArray ).length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa usar objetos para serem inclusos no array, pode-se montá-los e usar a função `push()` para receber no array.

Ficaria assim:

```js
let myArray = [];

myArray.push({'zero': 0})
myArray.push({'um': 1})
myArray.push({'dois': 2})

for(var i in myArray) {
    console.log(i)
}

//Descomente para ver o resultado final do array
//console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Em outras linguagens como PHP por exemplo é normal usar-se `myArray[] = 0;` para ir adicionando elementos a uma array.

Em JavaScript o `[]` é para aceder a propriedades. Assim se pretendes o mesmo efeito podes usar o `.push()` que faz isso mesmo, adicionar elementos no final da array, ou o `.unshift()` que adiciona no inicio da array.

```js
const myArray = [];

myArray.push({'zero': 0})
myArray.push({'um': 1})
myArray.push({'dois': 2})

console.log(myArray.length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Usando a array assim podes usar o forEach para iterar a array.